# Select Into Statement with modified value and wildcard

Tags: sql, select, db2

Is it possible to make a INSERT SELECT Statement for same table with modified values and wildcard for the rest colums?

I succeeded in getting a select insert statement with modified values. but not additionally with a wildcard. I would like to avoid having to name every single column.

V_ are variables :)

**that the way i want.**

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (
        T1.ID,
        T1.NAME,
        T1.SITE,
        T1.*) 
SELECT          T1.V_DE_SITE,
        T1.V_NAME,
        T1.V_SITE,
        T1.*
FROM Table_1 AS T1 WHERE T1.ID = V_SO_SITE;
```

**the following is possible i did it, but without wildcard! :( the table has some more columns**

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (
        ID,
        NAME,
        SITE) 
SELECT          V_DE_SITE,
        V_NAME,
        V_SITE
FROM Table_1 WHERE ID = V_SO_SITE;
```

Edit more info:

Is it possible to write:

```
Insert into tablexyz  (id, name, * ) select 3, 'hello', * from tablexyz where id = 100;
```

i change id and name for new data set and the * copy the Rest of colums 1:1 to new id.... thats all i need. I will not write down all the colums in statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wildcard in this case. But you may generate a template of such a statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  'INSERT INTO "'||TABSCHEMA||'"."'||TABNAME||'"'
--||' ('||LISTAGG('"'||COLNAME||'"', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLNO) ||')'
||x'0a'||'SELECT ' ||LISTAGG('"'||COLNAME||'"', x'0a'||', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLNO)
||x'0a'||'FROM "'||TABSCHEMA||'"."'||TABNAME||'";' STMT
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA='DB2ADMIN' AND TABNAME='EMPLOYEE'
GROUP BY TABSCHEMA, TABNAME;
```

The result is:

```
STMT
----
INSERT INTO "DB2ADMIN"."EMPLOYEE"
SELECT "EMPNO"
, "FIRSTNME"
, "MIDINIT"
, "LASTNAME"
, "WORKDEPT"
, "PHONENO"
, "HIREDATE"
, "JOB"
, "EDLEVEL"
, "SEX"
, "BIRTHDATE"
, "SALARY"
, "BONUS"
, "COMM"
FROM "DB2ADMIN"."EMPLOYEE";
```

Now you may specify expressions for needed columns in the `select` list accordingly.
If you uncomment the commented out line, all the table's columns in the `insert` are specified. You may omit such a specification if you want.

Comment: this does not work unfortunately I get the error message: SQL Error[42601]: An unexpected token "." was found following "LECT CURRENT C". Expected tokens may include: "," SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, Driver 4.26.14

Comment: The statements I provided work on any Db2 for LUW version as is. What's your Db2 version and platform? There is no `LECT CURRENT C` character sequence in my example. Do you run the statements as is? Or do you run your own statements?

Comment: i tested it with my statement. i took only this: INSERT INTO TEST_COLUMNS
SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP TS, C.* FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS C
; and modified to my own but it doesn't work.

Comment: why create Table Statement in your example?

Comment: i have db2 for LUW my platform is eclipse and the version is DB2 v11.1.1.1

Comment: This is just to demonstrate the complete reproducible example. You don't need to create the table in your case, of course. Seems, that you modified my insert statement incorrectly. Show your modified insert.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work i used this statement: INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT CURRENT 101 ID, 'testName' NAME, 101 SITE, C.* FROM SYSCAT.TABLE C WHERE ID = 5;

Comment: how do I have to define |INSERT INTO TEST_COLUMNS
SELECT HEEEEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRRREEEEE FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS C
;| the values ​​that I want to change in the target table and I want to pass?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your case initially. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thats the only way to change from example 10 colums 4 and the Rest 6 colums with * as wildcard to copy a set of data? Is it Not possible to write: insert into tablexyz  (id, name, * ) select 3,'hello', * from tablexyz where id = 100; | i change id and name for new data set and the * copy the Rest of colums 1:1 to new id.... thats all i need. I will not write down all the colums in statement.

Comment: It’s not possible.

Answer (score 0):

At your initial wanting insert statement, it has "where id = 100".  It means to me that you want to change one specific row.  If so, it may be possible to use **update** statement instead.  Here is a sample.

```
#!/bin/sh

db2 -v "drop database db1"
db2 -v "create database db1"
db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "create table t1 (c1 int, c2 char(10), c3 char(10), c4 char(10), c5 char(10))"
db2 -v "insert into t1 values ( 1, 'aaa', 'AAA', 'aaaa', 'AAAA')"
db2 -v "insert into t1 values ( 2, 'bbb', 'BBB', 'bbbb', 'BBBB')"
db2 -v "insert into t1 values ( 3, 'ccc', 'CCC', 'cccc', 'CCCC')"
db2 -v "select * from t1"
db2 -v "update t1 set c1=4, c2='ddd' where c1=3"
db2 -v "select * from t1"
db2 -v "terminate"
```

The first `select * from t1` shows below which is current data in the table t1.

```
C1          C2         C3         C4         C5
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 aaa        AAA        aaaa       AAAA
          2 bbb        BBB        bbbb       BBBB
          3 ccc        CCC        cccc       CCCC
```

And second one shows below after the **update** statement:

```
C1          C2         C3         C4         C5
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 aaa        AAA        aaaa       AAAA
          2 bbb        BBB        bbbb       BBBB
          4 ddd        CCC        cccc       CCCC
```

As above, we could change **C1=4 and C2='ddd'** but keep rest of columns for the row **C1=3** was.

Please kindly ignore, if I missunderstand your requiment.

Hope this helps.